# IDA Pro: How to change the virtual segment register T in a script

Tags: ida

If I press option/alt-G, IDA shows a dialog which allows me to change the value of the T segment register to 1 to indicate that the following bytes should be interpreted a Thumb code.

I would like to be able to change the value of T in a script.

What script function can I use?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SetRegEx(addr,"T",val,SR_user);
```

I found this by doing it manually, then clicking **File** | **Produce file** |  **Dump Database to IDC file..** and reading the commands used at the manual process location above.

Then read your idc.idc files to for the syntax of the above command.